# What's the basis for Niger's military to claim that the 2012 accord with the US was 'in violation of the “constitutional and democratic rules”'?

Tags: united-states, constitution, military, niger

[News](https://edition.cnn.com/2024/03/16/africa/niger-ends-us-military-agreement-intl-hnk/index.html) is that Niger's military government just denounced the 2012 accord with the US that was the basis of the latter's base and operations in Niger.

> “The government of Niger, taking into account the aspirations and interests of its people, decides with full responsibility to denounce with immediate effect the agreement relating to the status of military personnel of the United States and civilian employees of the American Department of Defense in the territory of the Republic of Niger,” Niger military spokesman Colonel Major Amadou Abdramane said in a statement on national television announcing the change.
>
> Abdramane added that the agreement between the two countries – signed in 2012, was imposed on Niger and had been **in violation of the “constitutional and democratic rules”** of the West African nation’s sovereignty.
>
> “This agreement is not only profoundly unfair in its substance but it also does not meet the aspirations and interests of the Nigerien people,” he said.

So, how was that 2012 accord agreed to in first place? Is there some merit to the claim it was in 'violation of the “constitutional and democratic rules”' of Niger? Yeah, that coming from a coup-installed military government is somewhat ironic, but still, does their claim the accord wasn't valid to begin with have some legal legs?

There's slighly more [detail](https://www.agenzianova.com/en/news/Niger-ends-military-cooperation-with-the-United-States/) in an Italian source:

> according to Niamey, the agreement itself, which was "unilaterally imposed" by the United States, through a "simple verbal note", on 6 July 2012, is illegitimate and "unjust".

(BTW, another [news piece](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2024/mar/17/niger-junta-repudiates-deal-allowing-us-military-bases-on-its-soil) notes that that spokesperson didn't quite ask for the US troops to leave, so it's somewhat possible they're just looking to renegotiate the terms of the accord. OTOH the PM appointed by the military recently [visited](https://www.rfi.fr/fr/afrique/20240118-le-niger-annonce-l-intensification-de-sa-coop%C3%A9ration-militaire-avec-la-russie) Russia and [Iran](https://www.voanews.com/a/iran-says-it-is-willing-to-help-niger-overcome-sanctions/7455787.html).)

Comment: They also revoked an accord with the EU, in December. https://apnews.com/article/niger-junta-eu-russia-security-73e8ed801478fa65b01818dd53df0c0e Haven't found any (rhetorical) details about that one, whether they also claim it was unfair, unconstitutional, and the like.

Comment: And in Jan they expelled some EU[CAP] personnel https://www.agenzianova.com/en/news/la-giunta-militare-del-niger-espelle-15-membri-della-missione-eucap/

Comment: I managed to find one of the three texts involved -- [the SOFA](https://www.state.gov/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/13-128-Niger-Defense-NotesCS.pdf). The other two ("Agreement concerning United States access to and use of
facilities in the Republic of Niger" and "Acquisition and cross-servicing agreement, with annexes") are marked "NP" in the US [index](https://www.state.gov/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/2019-TIF-Bilaterals-6.13.2019-web-version.pdf), which I'm guessing it means "not public" or "not published".

Comment: This is almost an answer: interestingly enough the Niger constitution [appears](https://www.constituteproject.org/constitution/Niger_2017) to have made treaty ratification a one-man job: "Article 168. The President of the Republic negotiates and ratifies the international treaties and agreements." So, if that was still in force, the Q is whether the [former] president did that.  Alas with [two of the] texts not public, I'm not sure. Also, somewhat unclear if he could delegate that job to the MFA, which seems to have happened in practice, at least with the SOFA.

Comment: OTOH, "Article 169
The treaties of defense and peace, the treaties and agreements relative to the international organizations, those which modify the internal laws of the State and those which involve [portent] [a] financial engagement from the State, may only be ratified following a law authorizing their ratification." So, it looks like defense treaties needed a 'law' too, but I'm not sure if this basing agreement qualified as such.

Answer (score 0):

It was agreed to by the previous government and the current one does not like it. The government was elected in 2010, in 2021 a coup was attempted but failed and in 2023 a coup succeeded and took over the government.

This goes back to an earlier question that you asked about them expelling French troops but not US troops. I am guessing it was just a matter of prioritizing who they kicked out of the country first.

[Has the Niger junta explained why they expelled French but not US troops?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/84849/has-the-niger-junta-explained-why-they-expelled-french-but-not-us-troops)

[Seventh Republic (2010–2023)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niger#Seventh_Republic_(2010%E2%80%932023))

> Following the adoption of a constitution in 2010 and presidential
> elections a year later, Mahamadou Issoufou was elected as the first
> president of the Seventh Republic; he was then re-elected in
> 2016.The constitution restored the semi-presidential system which had been abolished a year earlier. An attempted coup against him
> in 2011 was thwarted and its ringleaders arrested. Issoufou's time
> in office was marked by threats to the country's security, stemming
> from the fallout from the Libyan Civil War and Northern Mali conflict,
> an insurgency in western Niger by al-Qaeda and Islamic State, the
> spillover of Nigeria's Boko Haram insurgency into south-eastern Niger,
> and the use of Niger as a transit country for migrants (often
> organised by people-smuggling gangs). French and American forces
> assisted Niger in countering these threats.
>
> On 27 December 2020, Nigeriens went to the polls after Issoufou
> announced he would step down, paving the way to a peaceful transition
> of power. No candidate won an absolute majority in the vote:
> Mohamed Bazoum came closest with 39.33%. Per the constitution, a
> run-off election was held on 20 February 2021, with Bazoum taking
> 55.75% of the vote and opposition candidate (and former president) Mahamane Ousmane taking 44.25%, according to the electoral
> commission.
>
> On 31 March 2021, Niger's security forces thwarted an attempted coup
> by a military unit in the capital, Niamey. Gunfire was heard in the
> presidential palace. The attack took place two days before newly
> elected president Mohamed Bazoum was due to be sworn into office. The
> Presidential Guard arrested some people during the incident. On 2
> April 2021, Bazoum was sworn in as the President of Niger.
>
> Late on 26 July 2023, a coup by the military overthrew Bazoum, putting
> an end to the Seventh Republic and the government of Prime Minister
> Ouhoumoudou Mahamadou. On 28 July, General Abdourahamane Tchiani
> was proclaimed as the de facto head of state of the country.
> Former finance minister Ali Lamine Zeine was declared the new Prime
> Minister of Niger.

[Nigerien crisis (2023–present)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigerien_crisis_(2023%E2%80%93present))

> On 26 July 2023, a coup d'état occurred in Niger, during which the
> country's presidential guard removed and detained President Mohamed
> Bazoum. Subsequently, General Abdourahamane Tchiani, the Commander of
> the Presidential Guard, proclaimed himself the leader of the country
> and established the National Council for the Safeguard of the
> Homeland, after confirming the success of the coup.

Comment: I know that the previous government was [more] democratically elected. This answer doesn't say anything about the accord though (and constitutionality thereof).

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat It is a simple matter of the government changing and not liking what the previous government agreed to. That is why they expelled the French troops and why they expelled the US troops. It makes it a lot easier for them to do if they make claims that says the deal was bad to begin with.

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question as asked.  Of course the agreement was repudiated because it did not suit the current government.  The question asked specifically what the *violation of the “constitutional and democratic rules* argument is based on.  Not on generic reformulations of well-known political methods of expediency.  The stated reasoning behind the "fig leaf" are nowhere to be seen in this answer.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica And I am saying that was the excuse given to break the agreement.